# Prove that finding a cliques is NP-Complete?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

I presented my proof bellow, so is it complete (formal) proof.

**Proof :**

1- We can verify the solution in Polynomial time.

2- 3-SAT (NP-Complete) can be polynomialy reduced to clique! (as the following):

- We assume a formula 3-sat (F) as an example :

F= (X1 + X2 + X3).(^X1 + ^X2 + X3).(X4 + ^X3 + X2)

*note: ^X is the negation of X*

[[image]]

3-SAT is satisfiable $<=>$ $G(V,E)$ has a clique of size k>0.

**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQAWo.jpg) Clique =>3-SAT** : if we have a clique then it is SAT "by construction" literal represented as Node. such that no edge between $X_i$,$X_j$  belongs $C_k$, and no edge  between ^$X_i$ and $X_i$   in both $C_k, C_j$.
let  G has a clique of size k we can set each literal represented by a node v belongs the clique so 3-SAT is there.
since it is enough to have only **1** literal  = **true** in each clause.

**[2] 3-SAT => Clique:**
Let x be 3-SAT found in CNF, and it is satisfiable. => by the graph construction- we can connect all nodes that have **true** for each clause, and hence we have a clique #

Is my proof correct ?

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is correct and your steps are clear.

Comment: any other suggestion?